# Constraint error on elementcollection deleting with JPQL

Tags: hibernate, jpa

JPQL:

```
delete from Session where deviceId=:deviceId and username=:username
```

Error:

```
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: ERROR: update or delete on table "edge_session" violates foreign key constraint "fkh7j6o58rfwfumainodrxptobt" on table "session_contactmethods"
```

Session class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EDGE_SESSION")
public class Session {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass=ContactMethod.class)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Set<ContactMethod> contactMethods;

...
}
```

Should I be adding specific CascadeTypes to the contactMethods field? Because the foreign table holds an enum, I'm assuming the delete should be ok not to happen, because I want that list of enums to remain?

EDIT: Looks as though the session_contactmethods table it creates isn't just the enum values, but a join key with the Session.

```
# \d session_contactmethods
        Table "public.session_contactmethods"
     Column     |          Type          | Modifiers
----------------+------------------------+-----------
 session_id     | bigint                 | not null
 contactmethods | character varying(255) |
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fkh7j6o58rfwfumainodrxptobt" FOREIGN KEY (session_id) REFERENCES edge_session(id)

# select * from session_contactmethods;
 session_id | contactmethods
------------+----------------
          1 | EMAIL
          1 | TELEPHONE
          2 | TELEPHONE
          2 | EMAIL
(4 rows)
```

Comment: session_contactmethods sounds like a join table? Or is it the table which literally holds the ContactMethod enum/entity?

Comment: how can that list of enums remain?! They are dependent totally on the owner ... the Session object. PS, you don't need "targetClass" on that field, you have generics defining it

Comment: Yeah, I get that now, thought there might have been another table involved. Anyway, how do I get the delete to work then? Does it need an additional cascade annotation... I'd thought that wasn't required?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to remove objects in JPA.

1. Use `EntityManager.remove(...)`. This will cascade as required
   dependent on the cascade setting.
2. Use a `Bulk Delete` query. This will NOT cascade and you are basically saying *"Trust me, I know what I'm doing"*

You chose the latter, and it tries to do as you instructed and failed for the obvious reason that there is connected data. Use the first option, or remove the related objects first from the Session objects that are affected